# Displaying images from a json file onto HTML file but styling isnt working on them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

EDIT - just to clarify the images are displaying on my webpage with code exampled the styling (css) just isn't taking effect on any of the images in any way. If I give it a class, if I give it direct styling in the HTML (with style="") or if I use jQuerys .addClass or .css the styling just doesn't work.

So here is my html where the images are getting displayed into.

```
<div class="Hats2">

</div>
```

and now here is my jquery I am using to display the images

```
$(function() {

    var products = []

    $.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data.products, function(i, f) {
            var tblRow = '<div class="Hats"><img src=' + f.imUrl + '></div>'
            $(tblRow).appendTo(".Hats2");
        })
    })
})
```

And now I just have three line of CSS that changes the size of them under the class 'Hats'. Which I have given the image by trying it with the img element itself and the div is it in (like it is now)

```
.Hats {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

But for some reason the css isnt taking affect at all Ive tried all different styling like border-radius, etc. No styling works at all. Is it because I have given the class via jquery? Im just really confused. Here is my json file aswell just incase its needed.

```
{ "products": [
{
  "title": "Hat",
  "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pRaO7fFSL._SX395_.jpg"
},
{
  "title": "Hat2",
  "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41z9Fhv41lL._SY300_.jpg"
},
{
  "title": "Hat3",
  "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41y-UNn0QLL._SX342_.jpg"
}
]
}
```

Comment: @theonlygusti I have just copied your suggestion and replace it in my code and I still have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that even though the `.Hats` divs *are* correctly styled, that is, they are 200x200px as you say in the CSS, the image elements you're putting inside of them are larger.

[image]

Even though the images are children of the `.Hats` divs, they extend past the boundaries of their parents.

Just add this css rule:

```
.Hats > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

To **fit** the images inside of their parent div.

```js
var data = {
  "products": [
    {
      "title": "Hat",
      "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41pRaO7fFSL._SX395_.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "Hat2",
      "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41z9Fhv41lL._SY300_.jpg"
    },
    {
      "title": "Hat3",
      "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41y-UNn0QLL._SX342_.jpg"
    }
  ]
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each(data.products, function(i, f) {
    var tblRow = '<div class="Hats"><img src="' + f.imUrl + '"></div>';
    $(tblRow).appendTo(".Hats2");
  });
});
```

```css
.Hats {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.Hats > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Hats2">

</div>
```

Comment: Do you know why any other styling isn't working for .Hats?, for example, if I put display: none; under the Hats class in the CSS it doesn't work either?

Comment: @Jake123 putting `display:none;` within the styles for `.Hats` worked perfectly for me. It made all the images "disappear," which is what that style's meant to do.

Comment: Yeah I know thats what im trying to do hide them untill a button is clicked but they wont disappear

Comment: Sorry ignore that, I have managed it I had it set as '.Hats .Pants .Tops .Shoes { display none; }' and wasnt working for some reason but if I take the other 3 out and just leave it as .Hats it works :S

Comment: @Jake123 you need to separate those with commas if you want them _all_ to have display none. `.Hats, .Pants, .Tops, .Shoes { display none; }`

Answer (score 0):

This would not work.

```
$(tblRow).appendTo(".Hats2");
```

You are supposed to put

```
$(tblRow).appendTo($(".Hats2"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I have just tried this also and still the same problem.

Comment: Can you check if you can apply css to any element in the same file. Probably the stylesheet is not linked to the document. Or Can you make a jsfiddle or plunker page, it would be easier for us to debug

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the Hats class to img instead, like this:

```
$(function() {

var products = []

$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.products, function(i, f) {
        var tblRow = '<div><img class="Hats" src=' + f.imUrl + '></div>'
        $(tblRow).appendTo(".Hats2");
    })
    $(".Hats").css({width: "200px", height: "200px"});
});

})
```

Comment: Its working for me, is your test.json file in same folder?

Comment: @Jake123 this answer should work. Maybe it distorts the images, but your question doesn't say that's undesirable or make any specific requirements.